# Make Vista Bootable DVD with WIM downloaded files

Tags: windows-vista

I downloaded [**Windows Vista**](http://downloadsnfix.blogspot.com/2012/08/microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso.html) from Dell. Instead of a normal ISO file, some `.wim` files are provided. I followed the instructions to create a USB drive from the files, and came across this error

```
windows could not determine if this computer contains a valid system volume
```

which [**after looking**](http://nctritech.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/fix-the-windows-could-not-determine-if-this-computer-contains-a-valid-system-volume-error) appears to do with the fact that Vista is being installed from a flash drive rather than DVD. I saw the dell site an option for DVD, but it involves instructions like this

```
To the left will be your Vista folder, to the right make sure, you have checked
Make Image Bootable, changed the Developer ID: Microsoft Corporation, load
segment: 07C0 and Sectors to load: 4.
```

with no explanation as to **why** those settings need to be as they are. So I would like to create a DVD but would like another option if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use [`cdimage`](http://mydigitallife.info/how-to-make-vista-bootable-dvd-with-wim-downloaded-files)

Download [**cdimage**](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/15), should just need `cdimage.exe`

Run a command like this

```
cdimage -m -u2 -lVISTA_EN_DVD -bVista\boot\etfsboot.com Vista Vistax86.iso
```

with this example command the `Vista` folder is created when you run `X14-63452.exe` or similar file.

```
Usage: CDIMAGE [options] sourceroot targetfile

       -l  volume label, no spaces (e.g. -lMYLABEL)
       -m  ignore maximum image size of 681,984,000 bytes
       -u2 encode "UDF" file system without a mirror ISO-9660 file system
             (requires a UDF capable operating system to read the files)
       -b  "El Torito" boot sector file, no spaces
             (e.g. -bc:\location\cdboot.bin)
```

Comment: Q&A-style. Nice. +1 from me.