# How do I download the files for creating a windows Vista boot disk?

Tags: boot, windows-vista

So, I know where to go to get the required files:

http:/msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/boot.wim

http:/msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/install.wim

http:/msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msoffice/pub/X14-63452/X14-63452.exe

(add an extra slash to the links of course)

The issue is that boot.wim only downloads 56.0MB which seems to be only half of the file size as well as install.wim downloads only about 1/6 (430.0MB). Also to get a download to even start, I have to refresh the page over 10 times because otherwise it just says 'file not found"'. Is there any other way to get these files without going out and buying a boot disk? Maybe mirror links or anything? Or maybe even a fix to this issue.

Things I've tried:

1. I've used both Chrome and IE but the problem is the same
2. I've installed two separate download managers but the problem is the same.
3. I've tried it on a different computer in the home but the problem is the same.
4. I've tried it on a different ISP and on a different computer but the problem is the same.

edit: To make matters even worse, today the files won't even initiate a download.

Comment: try a download manager: http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm

Comment: @magicandre1981 2. I've installed two separate download managers but the problem is the same.

Comment: Do you mean Vista system repair disc? Or a full Installation disc?

Comment: [Go to this page using Chrome](http://downloadsnfix.blogspot.com/2012/08/microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso.html) Right click on the links you need and select "save as". See if this gets them for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://superuser.com/questions/552360/make-vista-bootable-dvd-with-wim-downloaded-files)

Comment: ok, Microsoft has taken down the digitalriver links: http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links So you can no longer get the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find them. Not sure how official it is, though.

install.wim: http://web.archive.org/web/20150116183656/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/install.wim

x14-63452.exe: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=2960

boot.wim: http://web.archive.org/web/20150101000000 / http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/boot.wim

Comment: install.wim http://web.archive.org/web/20120313164245/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/install.wim

Comment: boot.wim http://web.archive.org/web/20140112083817/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/boot.wim

Answer (score -1):

Getting older and harder to find:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150116183656/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/install.wim

http://web.archive.org/web/20150116183632/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/msshus/vista32/boot.wim

http://web.archive.org/web/20130308184940/http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msoffice/pub/X14-63452/X14-63452.exe

Comment: Please don't post answers that are only links.